# Android Development: how to make the uses-permissions work?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm wondering how can I make the uses permissions works?
In fact, i'm trying to make a phone call trhough a simple code but in the phone app, I've to press the green phone to confirm the call.
To make the app phone automatically I tried to introduce

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

in the AndroidManifest.XML but it doesn't change anything.
It doesn't matter if the uses-permission is there or not, I've to confirm the call.

Am I doing wrong with the permission?

Comment: Have you added the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>` permission in your manifest file ?

Comment: Yes I did.
But it doesn't change anything.
Thank you for asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the following permission (in AndroidManifest.xm):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

With this permission in place, I can setup a call using:

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
 callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

 startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I was stupidly using

Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
 callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

I wrote DIAL and not CALL.

Thank you for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

To make the call from your application you have to add the `CALL_PHONE` permission in your manifest file as below:

> ```
>  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
> ```

Comment: Thank you.
I've already done that. But it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

out side `application` tag and inside `manifest` tag in manifest.xml